# BlueSky Statistics: R Editor font size

Tags: editor

How can I change the font size of the R Editor in BlueSky Statistics v10?
I noticed an older response suggestion that ctrl-mouse wheel would do the trick but this does not work in v10. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a Zoom selector in the bottom right of the application window, which affects text everywhere, not just the R Editor portion.  Hope this helps!